# Next JS custom routing with custom locale

Tags: next.js, routes, internationalization, locale, middleware

guys. So what I'm trying to do that is exclude '/en' from my main page '/' and keep it everywhere else in the route. I'm figuring it out with middleware but can't get my head around. If you have any suggestions, please let me know down below.

next-config.ts

```
i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    locales: ['default','en', 'ru', 'uk', 'fr', 'es', 'pl', 'it', 'de'],
    localeDetection: false,
},
```

middleware.ts

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if (
        req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
        req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
        PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
    ) {
        return
    }

    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/' && req.nextUrl.locale === 'en') {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
    }

    if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default' && req.nextUrl.pathname !== '/') {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/en${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
    }

    return;
}
```

So it supposed to work this way :
'blabla.com'
'blabla.com/en/about'